# How to check in unit test that entity was added in the persistence context

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, junit

I have created an entity which among other field have a `private int id;` field. Now, I want to write a unit test that just confirms that it was added in the persistence context and that it got an id. However what should I check? The field is default initialized to 0, and since I don't use the wrapper class Integer (which I won't) I don't know how to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

The test won't be a unit test, as you want to make sure that someone is calling `setId()` on your entity. Unit test in this case would be to verify that the `entityManager.persist(myEntity)` is called for mocked `entityManager`.

As I understand, you would like an integration test for this. Try [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html), a rather good integration test framework. It can be used in JUnit framework. You can inject EJBs and mocked `EntityManager` into your JUnit, and it maintains an in-memory DB against which you may e.g. run JPA queries.

[Arquillian reference guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Reference+Guide)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `entityManager.persist(entity)` you may use `entityManager.merge(entity)` which returns the saved object. You can get id from returned object and check whatever you want.